# Capicom SHA1 hash gets computed different in Java

Tags: java, windows, vbscript, sha1, capicom

I am using `CAPICOM` assembly with `VBS` logic to encrypt some `text`, this works good but the problem starts when trying to replicate the same using `Java`.

**This is my VBS code:**

```
Option Explicit

Dim strToEncrypt: strToEncrypt = "Content-Type: plain/text; name=""C:\Users\Luigi\Desktop\hello.txt""" & vbCrLf & _
  "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=""C:\Users\Luigi\Desktop\hello.txt""" & vbCrLf & _
  "test"
Dim encryptedStr: encryptedStr = CRYPTO_SHA1(strToEncrypt)

WScript.Echo encryptedStr

Private Function CRYPTO_SHA1(strData) 'As String
  Const CAPICOM_HASH_ALGORITHM_SHA1 = 0

  Dim hash: Set hash = CreateObject("CAPICOM.HashedData")
  Dim util: Set util = CreateObject("CAPICOM.Utilities")
  Dim stm: Set stm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

  stm.Open
  stm.Type = 2 'adTypeText
  stm.Charset = "us-ascii"
  stm.WriteText strData
  stm.Position = 0
  stm.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

  hash.Algorithm = CAPICOM_HASH_ALGORITHM_SHA1
  hash.Hash stm.Read

  CRYPTO_SHA1 = util.Base64Encode(util.HexToBinary(hash.Value))
  CRYPTO_SHA1 = Left(CRYPTO_SHA1, Len(CRYPTO_SHA1)-Len(vbCrLf))

  stm.Close
  Set stm = Nothing
  Set util = Nothing
  Set hash = Nothing
End Function
```

**By debugging the above code, I can get the following:**

`Hash` object value is:

```
hash.Value = 636D0172D7FAC85AF9DB57FAE6C7D98B17DE5159
```

The final result as `encryptedStr` is:

```
encryptedStr = Y20Bctf6yFr521f65sfZixfeUVk=
```

---

**So, in `Java` I am trying to replicate the same and I assume this can be done by...**

1. Getting `SHA1` hash of the `String` or `InputStream` (because at `VBS` code there is an `stm` object that represents a `Stream`).
2. Use some `HexToBinary` method (by implementing this because by default this method doesn't exist in `Java`).
3. Use `BASE64Encoder` for the binary `String` from `SHA1` hash.
4. Finally, use `Left` method from `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils` (replicate of the `VBS` code) and then output `encryptedStr` as `base64` `String`.

**This is what I've tried so far in Java to at least generate the `SHA1` hash (supposed to be the same as `hash.Value` in `VBS`:**

```
package my.package;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.DigestInputStream;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class SHA1Encrypt {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String str = "Content-Type: plain/text; name=\"C:\\Users\\Luigi\\Desktop\\hello.txt\"" + "\n" +
                  "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"C:\\Users\\Luigi\\Desktop\\hello.txt\"" + "\n" +
                  "test";

        String SHA1FromString = getSHA1FromString(str);
        String SHA1FromIS = getSHA1FromIS(str);

        System.out.println("SHA1 from String is: " + SHA1FromString.toUpperCase());
        System.out.println("SHA1 from InputStream is: " + SHA1FromIS.toUpperCase());

    }

    public static String getSHA1FromString(String str) throws Exception {
        MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        sha1.update(str.getBytes());
        byte[] digest = sha1.digest();
        return byteArrayToHexString(digest);
    }

    public static String getSHA1FromIS(String str) throws Exception{

        MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        DigestInputStream   dis = new DigestInputStream(bis, sha1);

        while (dis.read() != -1); 
        byte[] digest = sha1.digest();
        return byteArrayToHexString(digest);
    }

    public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] b) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i=0; i < b.length; i++) {
          result += Integer.toString((b[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

**The above code will output the following:**

```
SHA1 from String is: 825CA9AF2795F3CCD41EC3B756CC7514E490842F
SHA1 from InputStream is: 825CA9AF2795F3CCD41EC3B756CC7514E490842F
```

---

### The problem:

- I am using the same `String` to be encrypted in both cases (`VBS` and `Java`).
- When I execute `VBS` code I get this `SHA1` hash value from `CAPICOM`:

  **636D0172D7FAC85AF9DB57FAE6C7D98B17DE5159**
- When I execute `Java` code I get this `SHA1` hash value:

  **825CA9AF2795F3CCD41EC3B756CC7514E490842F**
- I won't never get the same `base64` `String` as `encryptedStr` if `SHA1` hash is not the same.

---

### My Question:

What I am doing wrong and why did `SHA1` hash gets computed different in both cases. Can someone please explain what is happening or what is the correct way to implement this and get the same result in `Java`?

Just to know, I found this link that helps a little and says that they can get the same `hash` but doesn't fix the problem for my case:

http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/capicom-hasheddata-java-binary-files-help-44910362.html?page=2

If someone wants to install `CAPICOM` and test `VBS` code, you can do the following:

> 1. Copy "capicom.dll" to "C:\WINDOWS\system32"
> 2. Click on Start/Programs/Accessories/Command Prompt
> 3. Type "C:"
> 4. Type "cd C:\WINDOWS\system32"
> 5. Type "regsvr32.exe capicom.dll"
> 6. Click on the "OK" button.
> 7. Type "exit"

And download the `capicom.dll` yourself directly from `Microsoft` at:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=860EE43A-A843-462F-ABB5-FF88EA5896F6&displaylang=en

Comment: For one thing: you're not converting the same strings. Your VBScript code uses CR-LF as line breaks (`vbCrLf`), whereas the Java code uses only LF (`\n`).

Comment: [No](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved:

The correct way to express the `String` is using this way:

```
String str = "Content-Type: plain/text; name=\"C:\\Users\\Luigi\\Desktop\\hello.txt\"" + "\r\n" +
             "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"C:\\Users\\Luigi\\Desktop\\hello.txt\"" + "\r\n" +
             "test";
```

instead of `\n`, we need to use `\r\n`, then `SHA1` hashes will be the same.

Thanks Ansgar Wiechers for exposing this.